# Write function in controller below controller class?

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-5.6, laravel-controller

Is that a good practice to wrap some code from controller class method because it's too long and put that code in another custom function below controller class.

Here is controller method:

```
    public function store(UploadRequest $request)
{
    //Provjera duljine imena slike (max 20 znakova)
    if(!is_valid_name($request->file('file'))) {

        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['File name can\'t be longer than 20 characters.']);
    }

    $user = Auth::user();
    $time = time();
    $image = $request->file('file');

    //Dodaj trenutno vrijeme prije imena slike kako bi se slika mogla identificirati
    $image_name = $time . $image->getClientOriginalName();

    //Ako je slika png spremi ju bez konverzije
    if($image->getClientOriginalExtension() == "png")
    {
        Storage::put('public/images/'.$user->id.'/png/'.$image_name, file_get_contents($image));
        save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);
    }
```

Save_image_to_database() is my custom function that is written below controller class:

```
function save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time){

$db_image = new Image();

if($image->extension() == 'png')
{
    $db_image->path = $time . $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $db_image->png_size = $image->getClientOriginalSize();
}
else
{
    $path = $time . pathinfo($image->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME).'.png';
    $png_size = Storage::size('/public/images/'.$user->id.'/png/'.$path);

    $db_image->path = $path;
    $db_image->png_size = $png_size;
}

$db_image->user_id = $user->id;
$db_image->extension = $image->extension();
$db_image->size = $image->getClientSize();   
$db_image->save();

return redirect('/images');
```

}

**Problem is that redirect() method in custom function is not working, it redirects to blank window but the path in browser "localhost:8000/images" is correct.When I manually refresh the site then it works and the view is returned. If I move that redirect() method from custom function to controller store() then it works well.**

Comment: Should you maybe be returning the return of `save_image_to_database`? By that I mean use `return save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);`. If your controller function doesn't return a `view()`, `redirect()`, `response()`, etc, you'll see a blank page when the function finishes.

Comment: it redirects me to /images route that is in redirect(), but blank window appears, if I refresh it then the view appears

Comment: Then whatever function is handling the `/images` route has some logic in it that is preventing a `return`; perhaps post the controller function for that?

Comment: its weird that if I write that line of code "return redirect('/images');" below the call of save_image_to_database()" function in controller method then it works, but when it is in save_image_to_database() method then it wont work.

Comment: Are you using `return save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);` or not? I'm confused...

Comment: no, I have just  called that function like this: save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);

Comment: Try it with `return`, like I said in my first comment: *"By that I mean use `return save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);`"*

Comment: yes now it works, thanks

Comment: Have a read of the answer below; it basically says the same thing I did in these comments, so *"The most simple solution for you will be to return the response of helper function like `save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);`"*, so consider upvoting/accepting their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns `Response` object but controller doesn't use it

The most simple solution for you will be to return the response of helper function like

```
return save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);
```

However I would at least wrap it in `try-catch` to handle inability to save file like

```
try {
    save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // return error response
}

// if we got here image was successfully saved
return redirect('/images');
```

Now back to your question about if its a good experience to handle image as another controller method.. I'd say no, you want to keep your controllers very skinny and have only methods that are used by `Router`

I'd either move it into a `Trait` ([Traits in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)) and use that trait in the controller or make an `Image Service` and use it via [dependency injection](https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/bd857d9b0ac895df7604dd2e63b23afe).

Comment: Have a read of the comments above; also, consider adjusting your answer to `return save_image_to_database($image, $user, $time);` (you describe that, but then don't include it)